# Packaging java web application as exe

Tags: java, packaging, web-applications, software-packaging

Are there any free tools using which I can package my war (java web app) and tomcat as exe

Answer (score 1):

We distribute our web application [Kunagi](http://kunagi.org) as a .war, a debian package and also as a windows .exe. The windows versiont works as follows:

The .exe is created by a tool which exists on all windows machines, called iexpress. It is just an archive which is executable. On execution it extracts itself into a temporary directory and then executes a predefined command in this direcotry.

So wie pack a minimal embedded Tomcat (just 5 jars) into it, together with [Katokorbo](https://github.com/witek/katokorbo).

Katokorbo is a simple Swing application which downloads a war from the web and starts it with the embedded Tomcat. It also checks for new versions of the webapp on startup, asks the user if he wants to upgrade, starts a browser with the webapp and provides a gui to the user to view log output and for stopping the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maven can do that (http://maven.apache.org/) and I think Ant can too.